# Remove value after specific character in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I am using a pandas dataframe and I would like to remove all information after a space occures. My dataframe is similar as this one:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Australia' : pd.Series([0,'1980 (F)\n\n1957 (T)\n\n',1991], index=['Australia', 'Belgium', 'France']),
     'Belgium' : pd.Series([1980,0,1992], index=['Australia','Belgium', 'France']),
    'France' : pd.Series([1991,1992,0], index=['Australia','Belgium', 'France'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d, dtype='str')

df
```

I am able to remove the values for one specific column, however the split() function does not apply to the whole dataframe.

```
f = lambda x: x["Australia"].split(" ")[0]
df = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Anyone an idea how I could remove the information after a space occures for each value in the dataframe?

Comment: Yes, I have seen a similar question. But I want to return my whole dataframe without the information after the space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need convert all columns to `string`s and then apply `split` function:

```
df = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0])
```

Another solution:

```
df = df.astype(str).applymap(lambda x: x.split()[0])

print (df)
          Australia Belgium France
Australia         0    1980   1991
Belgium        1980       0   1992
France         1991    1992      0
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try using assign since the column names in this dataframe are "well tame" meaning not containing a space nor special characters:

```
df.assign(Australia=df.Australia.str.split().str[0])
```

Output:

```
          Australia Belgium France
Australia         0    1980   1991
Belgium        1980       0   1992
France         1991    1992      0
```

Or you can use apply and a lamda function if all your column datatypes are strings:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0])
```

Or if you have a mixture of numbers and string dtypes then you can use `select_dtypes` with `assign` like this:

```
df.assign(**df.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).apply(lambda x: x.str.split().str[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop over all columns and apply below:

```
for column in df:

    df[column] = df[column].str.split().str[0]
```